# HTML to PDF with Electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

i am using Electron / ReactJS / ExpressJS / LokiJS boilerplate for desktop apps.

Actually the problem is when i create a PDF from HTML it's working fine on Dev version, but when i try to do on Production version then it shows me an error message..below is the error.

> {"killed":false,"code":4294967295,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\electron-react-express-loki\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\phantom-html2pdf\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
>   C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\electron-react-express-loki\resources\app.asar\node_modules\phantom-html2pdf\lib\phantom-script.js
>   C:\Users\ALI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-19008vknA3FL4O2vT.html
>   C:\Users\ALI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-19008gl2nRzKfvwuZ.pdf
>   nofile A4 landscape 1cm false false 500 "}

Relevant Code that i use for Node.js

```
    var pdfNEW = require('phantom-html2pdf');

    app.post('/api/invoice', (req, res, next) => {
        let orgFileName = moment().unix() + ".pdf";
        let filename = "C:/SpaApp/Register/pdf/" + orgFileName;
        var pdfOptions = {
          html: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><h1>Hello</h1><p>World</p></body></html>',
          paperSize: {
            format: 'A4',
            orientation: 'landscape', // portrait
            border: '1cm'
          }
        };

        pdfNEW.convert(pdfOptions, (err, result) => {
          if (!err) {
            result.toFile(filename, () => {
              res.status(200).json({
                message: 'done'
              })
            });
          } else {
            res.status(500).json({
              message: err
            })
          }
        });
      })
```

If any solution is available then it will be a big help

Comment: Off topic but if you can install Chrome on your servers I recommend using pupeteer, phantom hasn't been updated since 2016 and is like rendering in IE11

Comment: tried...!
same error unfortunately..